# Preserving session with secure SSL-connection

Tags: java, android, session, ssl, https

There I connect to the authorization page, entree into account and load main page. 
How can I download other pages in the account without losing the connection?
And is it right?

Main class:

```java
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
int timeoutConnection = 10000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
int timeoutSocket = 10000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

HttpClient client = new MyHttpClient(httpParameters, getApplicationContext());
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://some.com/Login.aspx");

BufferedReader in = null;
try {

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uname", "name"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("upass", "pass"));
    request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity() .getContent()));

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
    String line = "";
    String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + NL);
    }
    in.close();
    String page = sb.toString();

    textview.setText(page);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {...}
```

And class MyHttpClient:

```java
public class MyHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient 
{    
  final Context context;
  public MyHttpClient(HttpParams hparms, Context context)
  {
    super(hparms);
    this.context = context;     
  }

  @Override
  protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
    SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    registry.register(new Scheme("https", new EasySSLSocketFactory(), 443));
    return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same request object (HttpPost), it should use the same connection unless you explicitly call releaseconnection on it. Refer to http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html

Comment: I did it!
In login I use HttpPost, and think it neet to use for going to other page, but as I see i Firefox with 'magic plugin' HttpFox second page opened with HttpGet and configureg headers request.
And Rohit thanks